# Sum of two continuous functions is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces.

Let $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$.

Then $f+g : X \rightarrow Y$ defined as
$f+g(x) = f(x)+g(x)$

I want to show that $f+g$ is continuous.

Let $U$ be an open set in $Y$.

Then how to show that its inverse image is open in $X$?

Comment: What is $Y$? A topological space is not necessarily a topological group.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $Y$ is endowed with a structure such that $+: Y\times Y\to Y$ is continuous (for example $Y$ is a topological group), note that $$f+g=+\circ (f,g)$$

so $f+g$ is continuous as the composition of continuous maps.